# Can I use DLC weapons in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Since I preordered on Origin, I have both the A-12 Raider shotgun and the M-55 Argus Assault rifle.

I kinda like them.

Does unlocking them as DLC make them available in multiplayer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Argus Assault rifle is *not* available for use online. I also have it unlocked but it is only present in the single player campaign.

I can't answer authoritatively for the Raider shotgun, but I expect that it works the same way as the Argus, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I didn't expect unlocking it in singleplayer made it instantly available. I was wondering if unlocking it singleplayer put it into the random card draws for multiplayer.